# Hibernate: getting entity from PostgreSQL view

Tags: postgresql, hibernate

Let's imagine that we have two entities in the database. We have a simple Server with a unique Id:

PostgreSQL:

```
CREATE TABLE public.servers (
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    name character varying(64) NOT NULL
);
ALTER TABLE ONLY public.servers
    ADD CONSTRAINT servers_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id);
```

Class entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "servers")
public class Server {

    @Id
    private long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "server", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Channel> channels;

    public Server() {}

    public Server(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        channels = new ArrayList<>();
    }

 // Getters and Setters...

}
```

Each Server can have several Channels that also have a unique id and belong to a server:

PostgreSQL:

```
CREATE TABLE public.channels (
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    server_id bigint NOT NULL,
    name character varying NOT NULL
);
ALTER TABLE ONLY public.channels
    ADD CONSTRAINT channels_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE ONLY public.channels
    ADD CONSTRAINT fkey_channel_server FOREIGN KEY (server_id) REFERENCES public.servers(id);
```

Class entity:

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "channels")
public class Channel {

    @Id
    private long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "server_sn")
    private Server server;

    public Channel() {}

    public Channel(Server server, String name) {
        this.server = server;
        this.name = name;
    }

    // Getters and Setters...

}
```

Next, I create a View in PostgreSQL:

```
CREATE VIEW public.summary AS
    SELECT servers.s_snowflake AS server_id, channels.c_snowflake AS channel_id, channels.name FROM servers
    JOIN channels ON servers.s_snowflake = channels.server_sn;
```

I want to get data from this view but I'm facing a problem on how to implement the class. I have tried something like this:

```
@Embeddable
class SummaryPK implements Serializable {
    private long server_id;
    private long channel_id;
}

@Entity
@Immutable
@Subselect("SELECT * FROM summary")
public class Summary  {

    @EmbeddedId
    private SummaryPK summaryPK;

    @MapsId("server_id")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = Server.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Server server;

    @MapsId("channel_id")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = Channel.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Channel channel;

    private String name;

    // Getters and Setters

}
```

In the program, I want to receive a list of Entity, for example, by passing the Server ID. Any idea how to implement a working structure here?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem, there were incorrect id in JoinColumn:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "server_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "channel_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
```